# Parsing a Multi Dimensional JSON string from URL

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl

I'm trying to access some values in JSON that are returned form this URL: https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker

Basically, I want to be able to get last, volume, ask & bid for "id":"FROST_BTC" (for example)

For now, I simply want to echo those out onto a php page.

Like:

```
Volume = 0.13
Ask = 0.033
Bid = 0.035
Last = 0.034
```

Due to the amount of data on the page, I'm not sure at all how to go about this ? Any thoughts, examples or readings so I can figure this one out ?

PHP would be preference, but open to try/learn anything.

Comment: Use php curl. You can get the json this way, convert it to array and you it however you like

Comment: First I would check their API documentation and see if they offer a method to get data for a specific id instead of fetching the entire ticker and filtering it on your end.

Comment: I have, they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try like this with [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $response_array = json_decode($response,1);
}
/*
# JUST FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSE
print '<pre>';
print_r($response_array);
print '</pre>';
*/
foreach($response_array as $k=>$v){
    echo "id = {$v['id']}, last = {$v['last']}, volume = {$v['volume']}, ask = {$v['ask']}, bid = {$v['bid']}";
    echo PHP_EOL;  
}
?>
```

> EDIT: As per comment

**Way 1**: use `break;` after printing 1st row

```
foreach($response_array as $k=>$v){
    echo "id = {$v['id']}, last = {$v['last']}, volume = {$v['volume']}, ask = {$v['ask']}, bid = {$v['bid']}";
    echo PHP_EOL;  
    break;
}
```

**Way 2** grab first row and then use loop to print it

```
$first_row = $response_array[0];
foreach($first_row as $k=>$v){
    echo "$k = $v";
}
```

**Way 3** using [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for specific row printing

```
$vacek_required = array_filter($response_array, function ($var) {
    return ($var['id'] == 'WGR_BTC');
});

foreach($vacek_required as $k=>$v){
    echo "$k = $v";
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. How do I get just one row of values for say ... id = WGR_BTC   if that is the only one U want to display ?

Comment: @Vacek see my edited answer for how to get only 1st row. Also see it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks Sunny, but it is not the first row I want, but some row in the middle. I want to be able to get a particular ID

Comment: ohh i got it see it now, you just need filter for WGR_BTC value

Comment: foreach($response_array as $k=>$v){
    if($v['id'] == "MARCO_BTC") {
        echo "id = {$v['id']}, last = {$v['last']}, volume = {$v['volume']}, ask = {$v['ask']}, bid = {$v['bid']}";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo PHP_EOL;  
    }
    
    }

Comment: @Vacek you can to it with `if` condition or `array_filter()`. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks again Sunny.